# Unable to resolve SqlConnection with connectionString as parameter using StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

I've been tasked to explicitly resolve an instance of SqlConnection using an IoC container, and passing in the connectionString parameter at runtime (not registration time). I've come up with the following test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class StructureMapTests
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        Container = new Container(_ =>
        {
            _.For<IDbConnection>().Add<SqlConnection>().Named("MyDefault").Ctor<string>("connectionString");
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void RegistrationUsingSM()
    {
        const string connectionString =
                "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
        var connection = Container.With(x =>
        {
            x.With("connectionString").EqualTo(connectionString);

        }).GetInstance<IDbConnection>("MyDefault");
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<SqlConnection>(connection);
        Assert.AreEqual(connectionString, connection.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

The test throws a StructureMapBuildPlanException when calling GetInstance. The message is:

Unable to create a build plan for concrete type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential

I don't know why SqlCredential is being referenced in this exception. I'm explicitly referring to the Named instance "MyDefault" when resolving IDbConnection. I've registered IDbConnection to explicitly use the SqlConnection constructor containing just the connectionString parameter. What does SqlCredential have to do with any of this? Why is it not resolving? Below is the stack trace:

> at StructureMap.Building.BuildPlan.Build(IBuildSession session, IContext context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\Building\BuildPlan.cs:line 152
>      at StructureMap.BuildSession.BuildNewInSession(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\BuildSession.cs:line 113
>      at StructureMap.Pipeline.NulloTransientCache.Get(Type pluginType, Instance instance, IBuildSession session) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\Pipeline\NulloTransientCache.cs:line 29
>      at StructureMap.BuildSession.ResolveFromLifecycle(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\BuildSession.cs:line 102
>      at StructureMap.SessionCache.GetObject(Type pluginType, Instance instance, ILifecycle lifecycle) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\SessionCache.cs:line 93
>      at StructureMap.BuildSession.FindObject(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\BuildSession.cs:line 223
>      at StructureMap.Container.BuildInstanceWithArgs(Type pluginType, Instance defaultInstance, ExplicitArguments args, String requestedName) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\Container.cs:line 1162
>      at StructureMap.Container.DoGetInstance(Type pluginType, ExplicitArguments args, String instanceKey) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\Container.cs:line 278
>      at StructureMap.Container.GetInstance[T](ExplicitArguments args, String instanceKey) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\Container.cs:line 204
>      at StructureMap.ExplicitArgsExpression.GetInstance[T](String name) in C:\BuildAgent\work\a395dbde6b793293\src\StructureMap.Shared\ExplicitArgsExpression.cs:line 118
>      at Scaffolding.Test.StructureMapTests.RegistrationUsingSM() in C:\Users\garre\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Scaffolding.Test\Scaffolding.Test\StructureMapTests.cs:line 29

EDIT: I was able to resolve the issue by passing a null SqlCredential object in the GetInstance method:

```
var connection = Container.With<string>(connectionString).With<SqlCredential>(null).GetInstance<IDbConnection>();
```

Apparently, the default constructor is ctor(string,SqlCredential), but still I am unable to specify ctor(string) as the constructor to use.